# Deployment Azure Data Factory using Azure DevOps with linked and nested templates

Tags: azure-devops, azure-data-factory, cicd

I am trying to deploy Azure Data Factory from dev to prod using Azure DevOps with linked and nested templates.
I get this error:

> 2022-09-14T09:36:04.6435061Z ##[error]Multiple error occurred: BadRequest,BadRequest,BadRequest,BadRequest,BadRequest,BadRequest,BadRequest,BadRequest,BadRequest,BadRequest. Please see details.
> 2022-09-14T09:36:04.6438171Z ##[error]Details:
> 2022-09-14T09:36:04.6440527Z ##[error]InvalidContentLink: The provided content link 'Azure.Deployments.Core.Entities.DeploymentTemplateContentLink' is invalid or not supported. Content link must be an absolute URI not referencing local host or UNC path.
> 2022-09-14T09:36:04.6443077Z ##[error]InvalidContentLink: The provided content link 'Azure.Deployments.Core.Entities.DeploymentTemplateContentLink' is invalid or not supported. Content link must be an absolute URI not referencing local host or UNC path.
> 2022-09-14T09:36:04.6445622Z ##[error]InvalidContentLink: The provided content link 'Azure.Deployments.Core.Entities.DeploymentTemplateContentLink' is invalid or not supported. Content link must be an absolute URI not referencing local host or UNC path.
> 2022-09-14T09:36:04.6448113Z ##[error]InvalidContentLink: The provided content link 'Azure.Deployments.Core.Entities.DeploymentTemplateContentLink' is invalid or not supported. Content link must be an absolute URI not referencing local host or UNC path.
> 2022-09-14T09:36:04.6450611Z ##[error]InvalidContentLink: The provided content link 'Azure.Deployments.Core.Entities.DeploymentTemplateContentLink' is invalid or not supported. Content link must be an absolute URI not referencing local host or UNC path.
> 2022-09-14T09:36:04.6452984Z ##[error]InvalidContentLink: The provided content link 'Azure.Deployments.Core.Entities.DeploymentTemplateContentLink' is invalid or not supported. Content link must be an absolute URI not referencing local host or UNC path.
> 2022-09-14T09:36:04.6455335Z ##[error]InvalidContentLink: The provided content link 'Azure.Deployments.Core.Entities.DeploymentTemplateContentLink' is invalid or not supported. Content link must be an absolute URI not referencing local host or UNC path.
> 2022-09-14T09:36:04.6460185Z ##[error]InvalidContentLink: The provided content link 'Azure.Deployments.Core.Entities.DeploymentTemplateContentLink' is invalid or not supported. Content link must be an absolute URI not referencing local host or UNC path.
> 2022-09-14T09:36:04.6462617Z ##[error]InvalidContentLink: The provided content link 'Azure.Deployments.Core.Entities.DeploymentTemplateContentLink' is invalid or not supported. Content link must be an absolute URI not referencing local host or UNC path.
> 2022-09-14T09:36:04.6464859Z ##[error]InvalidContentLink: The provided content link 'Azure.Deployments.Core.Entities.DeploymentTemplateContentLink' is invalid or not supported. Content link must be an absolute URI not referencing local host or UNC path.
> 2022-09-14T09:36:04.6467123Z ##[warning]Validation errors were found in the Azure Resource Manager template. This can potentially cause template deployment to fail. Task failed while creating or updating the template deployment.. Please follow https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/templates/template-syntax

[Mistake](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TNdn7.png)

How to fix this error?

Comment: is this helpful? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/465909/unable-to-deploy-arm-templates-bad-request-error.html

Comment: @Utkarsh Pal 
It's not helpful for me? because I don't understand which links in my template are wrong.

Comment: You need to figure out that then only we can repro it